# How to remove clients from Authlib oauth client registry

Tags: python, authlib

I'm using Authlib's Flask client integration and I want to be able to "remove" a registered client from the oauth registry. The reason is that part of a test I'm writing involves registering a test client. Registering with `oauth.register(...)` is fine, but I essentially just want to clear out the registry after my test completes.

Is it sufficient to just delete the keys of the `oauth._clients` and `oauth._registry` dicts, or is there some other data that is persisted? I don't see an explicit method to do this.